HandshakeException: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: self signed certificate error
I trying to get the user's current location in my mobile app. so that, I am calling the getcitydetail api call....and i am getting this error "HandshakeException: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: self signed certificate error"
I tried to by-pass this error by temporarily bypass SSL verification by modifying the HTTP client to accept self-signed certificates, but getting this error.

refer this answer it help to you and solve your problem.

This question is similar to: How to solve Flutter CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error while performing a POST request?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

class AppHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = ((cert, host, port) => true);
  }
}



execute this before API called:
DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
// for os 7 override http badCertificateCallback
if((androidInfo.version.sdkInt ?? 30) < 26) {
  HttpOverrides.global = new AppHttpOverrides();
}


using 'device_info_plus' package for getting os api level
